# How can the Brachistochrone problem be solved if we set the slope at both end points to be 0?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

If the the two end points are $(0,0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$, then $y'(0)=0$ and $y'(x_1)=0$.
I have no idea how this constraint can be set up while solving the Euler-Lagrange Equation. Also, is there some general method for optimizing functionals with similar single point constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the fact that solution curves to the [Brachistochrone problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) are [strictly convex functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). (Heuristically, we can save a bit of time by bending a straight line infinitesimally downwards. We leave it to the reader to give a mathematically precise proof.)

This means that the slope is a strongly increasing function. Therefore demanding a zero slope in both endpoints are two mutually incompatible boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The brachistochrone problem is a workhorse in calculus of variations. (You can look it up in many textbooks.) It is usually stated as
$$\min \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left(\frac{1 + (y^\prime)^2}{y} \right)^{1/2} dx$$
Since the integrand $F(x, y, y^\prime)$ does not explicitly depend on $x$, the Euler equation reduces to the special case
$$F-y^\prime F_{y^\prime} = \mbox{constant}$$
and the resulting equation can be solved by separating variables.